# Connecting .php file to mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, localhost

What I am trying to do is get mysql database to load up my .php file. I am using hostgator to run mysql database server. So far what i have for sql is a table with three columns.

- int: id (primary key / A.I.)
- varchar: name
- text: message

I save the table and name it "test" and the database is called "testdb"

My php file (tutorialTest.php) looks like this:

```
<?php

$username = "nfoggia_nick";
$password = "imnick";
$database = "nfoggia_testdb";

mysql_connect(localhost, $username, $password);

@mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to find database");

$name =$_GET["name"];
$message = $_GET["message"];

$query = "INSERT INTO test VALUES (' ', '$name', '$message')";
mysql_querry($query) or die(mysql_error("error"));
mysql_close();
?>
```

I added the .php file in my file directory on hostgator and now my problem is this:
I know that this code will do nothing, but when i type in

```
 http://localhost/tutorialTest.php
```

the web browser says "browser cannot connect to local host" when it should just show a blank screen. Any help? What did i do wrong?

EDIT:
I moved my php file to the document root for my website and now when i run the

```
http://myWebsiteName/tutorialTest.php this shows up:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_querry() in     /home2/nfoggia/public_html/tutorialTest.php on line 15
```

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ). FYI, you are also wide open to [SQL injections](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)

Comment: you say hostgator but url is loclahost? im confused

Comment: If the file is on some hostgator server, then the URL should be the URL of your server, not the localhost

Comment: I can't understand very well but the only reason that i can found is that you are writting but the directory file... check it

Comment: Localhost is your computer. What is your hosting URL ?

Comment: well it should be my website name right? i've tried that (myWebsitesName/tutorialTest.php)

Comment: where is this file located? on the webserver in the right directory or on your computer?

Comment: please see update above. I put the file in a new place

Comment: I would post it as a new question.

Comment: @nfoggia mysql_querry() is not a function. current the spell of query.  Use mysql_query() instead. But highly re-comment to change to MYSQLi.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Before mentioning all the PHP errors, your URL is wrong.

`localhost` means your local computer, instead of your hosting environment, which you mentioned is hostgator.

- Do you upload your PHP to hostgator server?
- Is the MySQL database schema exist in hostgator environment?

Your URL should look like : http://www.hostgator.com/whatever/tutorialTest.php (or under your domain name). Anything but not `http://localhost`

---

First of all, remove the `@` to reveal the error.

For MySQL connection, the first parameter is a string, so you have to enclose it with single quotes, that is:

```
mysql_connect('localhost', $username, $password);
```

Last, you have multiple PHP errors :

```
mysql_querry($query)
```

You misspelled the function. Also, `mysql_error()` accepts link identifier as optional parameter instead of a string.

---

As a side note, stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. Also, your code is subjected to SQL Injection attack, as you directly allow GET values to be inserted in your query.

Comment: All true, but none of it related to 'no page found'.

Comment: Agree with you, Mike. OP does not provide enough information for the 404 error.

Comment: the window says that it cannot connect to local host. Ill add a photo of what i get in the browser in a few moments

Comment: Localhost is your computer, not hostgator. Change the link.

Comment: you misspelled `mysql_query()`, as said in the answer.